# osCommerce SEO url class conflicting Abandoned Sales

Tags: php, oscommerce

I am using CRE Loaded eCommerce where I have used Ultimate SEO url module for search engine friendly urls. But I marked 1 thing that when the SEO URL module is activated, the abandoned sales module goes broken.

Normally the admin menu displays like this..

[image]

Which works fine but when I am activating the SEO module, the url displays like this and clicking on that takes me to 404 page,

[image]

I have done some trial and error method and found the the seo.class.php file is doing something to create this error. Can anyone help me out to find this error.

I am using CRE Loaded 6.2
And [Ultimate SEO URL Addon](http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/2823)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your PHP error log on your server to see what is going wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

CRE loaded has it's own version of SEO Urls, have you tried that?

http://store.loadedcommerce.com/seo-urls-add-on-p-45.html (old legacy site)

also - wow, 6.2 is old you should upgrade to 6.5 or Loaded 7

http://loadedcommerce.com/ (new supported releases)

Comment: CRE Seo is there and also activated but not working. Don't know why. That's why I went for other solutions.